# azure data factory with databricks analytics

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-factory

i am bit confuse to implement the databricks with azure data factory. My question is how to set up databricks activities with pipeline and do the transform data based on requirement.
I have done with some set up like 
created linked service for source and destination and stage database.
created dataset for all and created pipeline for forech activity. its working fine without transform data. 
Now i have to do some transformation using databricks so how do we set it up. could you please guide me to set it up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please read the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook.